# How do I check to see if a value is an integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I see that within MySQL there are `Cast()` and `Convert()` functions to create integers from values, but is there any way to check to see if a value is an integer?  Something like `is_int()` in PHP is what I am looking for.

Comment: so sadly we must create is_int() function in Mysql

Answer (score 246, accepted):

I'll assume you want to check a string value. One nice way is the REGEXP operator, matching the string to a regular expression. Simply do

```
select field from table where field REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$';
```

this is reasonably fast. If your field is numeric, just test for

```
ceil(field) = field
```

instead.

Comment: The 'ceil(field) = field' test is a nice idea, but as @Jumpy pointed out, it fails on non-numeric data: SELECT ceil('four') = 'four'; -> 1

Comment: @MatthewCornell, He said if your field is numeric. That's so you can test if a number is an integer. It won't work on strings, that's why the first option is there.

Comment: If the data might include whitespace, this would fail. Consider testing trim(field), possibly with an extra arg to remove newlines.

Comment: the the data is numeric, may do this too: select ((field % 1) = 0);

Comment: Thanks, but for the numeric comparison, I think you need not(strcmp(ceil(field),field))

Answer (score 15):

Match it against a regular expression.

c.f. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,1907,38488#msg-38488 as quoted below:

> Re: IsNumeric() clause in MySQL??
>
> Posted by: kevinclark ()
>
> Date: August 08, 2005 01:01PM
>
> I agree. Here is a function I created for MySQL 5:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (sIn varchar(1024)) RETURNS tinyint
RETURN sIn REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';
```

> This allows for an optional plus/minus sign at the beginning, one optional decimal point, and the rest numeric digits.

Comment: Thanks, your solution takes care of decimals also

Answer (score 14):

Suppose we have column with alphanumeric field having entries like

```
a41q
1458
xwe8
1475
asde
9582
.
.
.
.
.
qe84
```

and you want highest numeric value from this db column (in this case it is 9582) then this query will help you

```
SELECT Max(column_name) from table_name where column_name REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: *'10000'* is higher, but your query would still return *'9582'*.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the simple solution for it
assuming the data type is varchar

```
select * from calender where year > 0
```

It will return true if the year is numeric else false

Comment: In a varchar, this will also return true if the first character is numeric.

Comment: Didn't notice that. up-voting your comment :)

Answer (score 8):

This also works:

```
CAST( coulmn_value AS UNSIGNED ) // will return 0 if not numeric string.
```

for example

```
SELECT CAST('a123' AS UNSIGNED) // returns 0
SELECT CAST('123' AS UNSIGNED) // returns 123 i.e. > 0
```

Comment: what about `SELECT CAST('12a34' AS UNSIGNED)`, which returns `12`?

Comment: This works perfect if you need to test for non-numeric items, this deserves more +1s. The other answers are harder to reverse the test to find the non-numeric items.

Comment: @DrCord this does not work for the case Mike C described, hence is very unreliable

Comment: This does not work if we have INTEGER VALUE = 0.
`SELECT CAST( 'empty' AS UNSIGNED ); /*return 0*/`

`SELECT CAST( 1 AS UNSIGNED ); /*return 1*/`
`SELECT CAST( 0 AS UNSIGNED ); /*return 0*/`
```

Answer (score 6):

To check if a value is Int in Mysql, we can use the following query.
This query will give the rows with Int values

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE concat('',col * 1) = col;
```

Comment: This will also select non-integer numbers (eg. *'3.5'*).

Answer (score 5):

The best i could think of a variable is a int Is a combination with MySQL's functions `CAST()` and `LENGTH()`. 
 
This method will work on strings, integers, doubles/floats datatypes.

```
SELECT (LENGTH(CAST(<data> AS UNSIGNED))) = (LENGTH(<data>)) AS is_int
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff40cd/44

> it will fail if the column has a single character value. if column has
>   a value 'A' then Cast('A' as UNSIGNED) will evaluate to 0 and
>   LENGTH(0) will be 1. so LENGTH(Cast('A' as UNSIGNED))=LENGTH(0) will
>   evaluate to 1=1 => 1

True Waqas Malik totally fogotten to test that case. the patch is.

```
SELECT <data>, (LENGTH(CAST(<data> AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST(<data> AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST(<data> AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH(<data>)) END AS is_int;
```

**Results**

```
**Query #1**

    SELECT 1, (LENGTH(CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH(1)) END AS is_int;

| 1   | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 1      |

---
**Query #2**

    SELECT 1.1, (LENGTH(CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST(1.1 AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST(1.1 AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH(1.1)) END AS is_int;

| 1.1 | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| 1.1 | 0      |

---
**Query #3**

    SELECT "1", (LENGTH(CAST("1" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("1" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("1" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("1")) END AS is_int;

| 1   | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 1      |

---
**Query #4**

    SELECT "1.1", (LENGTH(CAST("1.1" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("1.1" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("1.1" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("1.1")) END AS is_int;

| 1.1 | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| 1.1 | 0      |

---
**Query #5**

    SELECT "1a", (LENGTH(CAST("1.1" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("1a" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("1a" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("1a")) END AS is_int;

| 1a  | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| 1a  | 0      |

---
**Query #6**

    SELECT "1.1a", (LENGTH(CAST("1.1a" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("1.1a" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("1.1a" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("1.1a")) END AS is_int;

| 1.1a | is_int |
| ---- | ------ |
| 1.1a | 0      |

---
**Query #7**

    SELECT "a1", (LENGTH(CAST("1.1a" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("a1" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("a1" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("a1")) END AS is_int;

| a1  | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| a1  | 0      |

---
**Query #8**

    SELECT "a1.1", (LENGTH(CAST("a1.1" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("a1.1" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("a1.1" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("a1.1")) END AS is_int;

| a1.1 | is_int |
| ---- | ------ |
| a1.1 | 0      |

---
**Query #9**

    SELECT "a", (LENGTH(CAST("a" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("a" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("a" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("a")) END AS is_int;

| a   | is_int |
| --- | ------ |
| a   | 0      |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/NNXJ9cPwxjNPz9NknsSGU/0)

Comment: it will fail if the column has a single character value. if column has a value 'A' then Cast('A' as UNSIGNED) will evaluate to 0 and LENGTH(0) will be 1. so LENGTH(Cast('A' as UNSIGNED))=LENGTH(0) will evaluate to 1=1 => 1

Comment: Thanks for the comment that case was indeed untested @WaqasMalik working and testing a patch right now.. something like `SELECT "a", (LENGTH(CAST("a" AS UNSIGNED))) = CASE WHEN CAST("a" AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN CAST("a" AS UNSIGNED) ELSE (LENGTH("a")) END AS is_int;`

Comment: This is such a cool solution. I think it fails for negative integers, does it change anything substantive (in edge cases) to switch your solution to signed integers? I've been testing using your fiddle as the base. `set @val = '1.';
SELECT @val, LENGTH(CAST(@val AS SIGNED)) = IF(CAST(@val AS SIGNED) = 0, CAST(@val AS SIGNED), LENGTH(@val)) AS is_int;` This refactoring handles all above cases, but even my adjustment doesn't handle -1.0 or '-1.' Again, a super cool solution.

Comment: thanks for the positive and kind words @spen.smith not tested fully but try with ABS() -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/NNXJ9cPwxjNPz9NknsSGU/3

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
WHERE table.field = "0" or CAST(table.field as SIGNED) != 0
```

to test for numeric and the corrolary:

```
WHERE table.field != "0" and CAST(table.field as SIGNED) = 0
```

Comment: CAST(table.field) != 0 will not work as it needs a type to cast.

Comment: This works perfect if you need to test for non-numeric items, this deserves more +1s. The other answers are harder to reverse the test to find the non-numeric items.

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers like "0000", " 0" (space) and "7x" (which is considered a number).

Comment: @MichaelGrazebrook I suppose you could do a regexp for the first two cases. "7x" is considered a number? "0x7" is a number, but 7x?

Comment: @Tom Auger: Another answer covered the regex type solutions. What I meant by "7x is considered a number" is that this statement is true: select 7 = '7q'

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the regular expressions listed above, but they do not work for the following:

```
SELECT '12 INCHES' REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$' FROM ...
```

The above will return `1` (`TRUE`), meaning the test of the string '12 INCHES' against the regular expression above, returns `TRUE`.  It looks like a number based on the regular expression used above.  In this case, because the 12 is at the beginning of the string, the regular expression interprets it as a number.

The following will return the right value (i.e. `0`) because the string starts with characters instead of digits

```
SELECT 'TOP 10' REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$' FROM ...
```

The above will return `0` (`FALSE`) because the beginning of the string is text and not numeric.

However, if you are dealing with strings that have a mix of numbers and letters that begin with a number, you will not get the results you want.  REGEXP will interpret the string as a valid number when in fact it is not.

Comment: This is incorrect. Did you test it? When I run your first example, it returns `FALSE`, as expected, because the regex ends with `$` which means the end of the string, so it is checking for only numbers, as intended by the author.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for VARCHAR where it begins with a number or not..

```
WHERE concat('',fieldname * 1) != fieldname
```

may have restrictions when you get to the larger NNNNE+- numbers

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for single char strings `set @val = '5';
SELECT @val, concat('', @val * 1) != @val is_int;`

Answer (score 0):

for me the only thing that works is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (SIN VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS TINYINT
RETURN SIN REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';
```

from kevinclark all other return useless stuff for me in case of `234jk456` or `12 inches`

Answer (score 0):

someone above says to test using ceil(@my_num) = @my_num.

This does not quite do the trick, however. Notice that ceil(2.7) does equal 3:

select ceil(3) = 3 as test1, ceil(3.2) = 3 as test_2, ceil(2.7) = 3 as test_3;

If you are trying to determine if a variable is an int, this test does not give you enough information.