# MySQL return only the rows which are numeric

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check to see if a value is an integer in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql)

I have been been trying to select only the numeric rows from a field in mysql.

A sample of the data in the database would be:

'1234543'
'12f4231'
'fdfrgr34'
etc.

I want my select statement to only return the numeric rows.

So in this case the only row I would get back would be the '1234543' row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex, for positive numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'
```

Some adjustments are needed if you want to allow leading/trailing whitespace though.