# Is there a way to query mysql and only pull results that are numbers?

Tags: mysql

I have this simple query and was wondering if it is even possible to only pull info where `arc` is only equal to numbers and not text.

Code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comics` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: what is `arc`? a field in the table? why do you need only numbers?

Comment: yeah arc is a field, and i only need numbers because there is an order of processing where if arc is not a number then it is not ready to be processed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no "IsNumeric()" function in MySql.

You can, however, use a regex:

> [How do I check to see if a value is an integer in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql)
>
> I'll assume you want to check a string value. One nice way is the
>   REGEXP operator, matching the string to a regular expression. Simply
>   do

```
select field from table where field REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$';
```

> this is reasonably fast. If your field is numeric, just test for

```
ceil(field) = field
```

Similarly:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,1907,38488

Comment: The `ceil(field) = field` example tests to see if the value in a floating point column is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

For academic purposes, I offer the case of implicit conversions. When performing a math function, MySQL will attempt to convert a string to an integer, returning 0 if it fails.

So...

```
SELECT 1 * '1'
```

Returns:
`1`

```
SELECT 1 * 'hello'
```

Returns
`0`

So if `0` is not a valid number in your field, you can simply do

```
SELECT * FROM comics WHERE arc * 1 > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
select * from comics where arc REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```