# How to select all rows where mycolumn is an integer value?

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be a good way to select all the rows from a table where a column is an unsigned integer,
for example here is some pseudo-sql

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn IS UNSIGNED INTEGER
```

So that strings 'abc' and numbers like '12.3' and '12.0' would **not** match, but integers like '123' would.

Where mycolumn is type text/varchar

Comment: the column is text/char type?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: The question states "column is an unsigned integer".

Comment: @weenoid in that case the question would be useless, all values will be positive integers. The OP wants to `select all rows where`, where `where` is a SQL clause :)

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Please see my updated answer. Is there any reason why you can't just set the datatype of mycolumn to be an integer?

Comment: Do you need 12.0 matched or not? And are all values in column numeric or is can contain non numeric data also?

Comment: @weenoid change the datatype of the table column? no, it contains other number based values, which I'm trying to filter out.

Comment: @elevener no, 12.0 must not be matched as it's a float.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Shouldn't that be simple enough?

Comment: Try [0-9] instead of \d. Might be due to backslash.

Comment: It does not match 12.0. Dunno is it bug or a feature.

Comment: @Agent_L explain, what should I update in the question? I updated it, don't know if I did it like you thought that I should?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky The rejection of 12.0 is very important, but it's not easy to find in comments. The title suggests it's about integer VALUE, not writing convention.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from mytable  
where cast(mycolumn as int) = mycolumn
```

[Updated Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95be9/1)

### EDIT

I did not see you have a `varchar` column. Try this instead:

```
select * from myTable 
where cast(cast(myColumn as decimal(8,2)) as signed) = 
      cast(myColumn as decimal(8,2))
```

Comment: I made a sample table mytable and tried it and got: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) = mycolumn' at line 2`

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Do not write int in `'`. Use `as int` and not `as 'int'`

Comment: @juergend the test should be with `myColumn varchar(30)`. THe OP has at char type column

Comment: now is perfect! +1 from me. However, the OP states in comments that values like 12.0 should be filtered out. IT's not what he initially asked

Comment: @juergend using your exact sql on a test table, where it's using `as int` and `as float` without the single quotes, still getting that error though.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Please post the exact query you are trying and I will have a look.

Comment: @juergend `select * from mytable  
where cast(cast(mycolumn as float) as int) = cast(mycolumn as float);`

Comment: @juergend I tried it in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2f21/1 and it worked, but fails to do so in my server, instead I get this error, maybe it has something to do with mysql? `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) as int) = cast(mycolumn as float)' at line 1`

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Yes it is about MySQL. I tried it accidently with SQL Server and not with MYSQL. I am trying to find an answer to the problem.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: I updated my answer. It works now but not with numbers like `12.0`. You should accept Robin's answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10594/discussion-between-yurikolovsky-and-juergen-d)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = FLOOR(mycolumn)
```

//edit: OK, as question is specified, this answer no longer fits.
It will reject 12.3 but match 12 AND 12.0 (what turned out to be not indended).

The revised problem can't be solved mathematically, only way is to match characters, as Robin Castlin did.

Comment: Would this be true for "12.0"?

Comment: This would result in a value of 12.3 matching a row with an ID of 12 when the OP has stated that this isn't the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it works. If you don't believe me, then try it on demo.phpmyadmin.net as I just did.

Comment: Apologies, I thought 'FLOOR(mycolumn)' was supposed to represent the value being passed in, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test_int(
test_value varchar(5)
)

insert into test_int values('a')
insert into test_int values('1')
insert into test_int values('12.3')

select *
from test_int 
where isnumeric(
cast(test_value as varchar)) = 1
```

result

```
1
12.3
```