# Nested CAST not working

Tags: mysql, casting, nested

Why is a nested cast NOT working in MySQL? (It does using SQL Server)

```
select cast(cast(myColumn as decimal(5,2)) as int) from myTable
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/682a6/12)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is the purpose of casting as `UNSIGNED`, only then to interpret the resulting data as a signed `INT`?  Won't this have the same effect as directly doing `CAST(myColumn AS INT)`?

Comment: @eggyal: I changed my example. The question came up trying to find integer numbers in a varchar field and ignoring the decimal numbers like that: `select * from tab where cast(cast(myColumn as decimal(5,2)) as int) = cast(myColumn as decimal(5,2))`

Comment: To accomplish that, you'll probably find it easier to test your columns against [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql) for more info.

Comment: @eggyal: You are absolutly right. But still I would like to know what to do if a nested cast would be needed.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm hoping someone else might be able to shine some light on it for you, as the only thing I can think of is to perform the first `CAST` in a subquery and then the second in an outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

> **`CAST(expr AS type)`** [...]
>
> **`CONVERT(expr,type)`** [...]
>
> The ***`type`*** can be one of the following values:
>
> - **`BINARY[(N)]`**
> - **`CHAR[(N)]`**
> - **`DATE`**
> - **`DATETIME`**
> - **`DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`**
> - **`SIGNED [INTEGER]`**
> - **`TIME`**
> - **`UNSIGNED [INTEGER]`**

So, just follow the manual:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(myColumn AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS SIGNED) FROM myTable
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(myColumn AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS UNSIGNED) FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is working on the concept of nested cast.

cast(sum(cast(Column_name int )+ cast(Column_name as int))  as bigint) as payment from table_name