# MySQL statement select where a column is NOT a number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problematic script that ran, so i need to select all rows that contain values that is not a straight up integer. How do I do this? ISSTRING was on a Google search but I get an error from it saying ISSTRING does not exist. :(

So far I've muddled with:

```
SELECT id, area, city FROM `homes` WHERE ISSTRING(`area`) OR ISSTRING(`city`)
```

With no luck whatsoever...

Comment: You can do it via regular expressions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql. You'd only have to add a `NOT`.

Comment: If `area` and `city` are supposed to be of type integer only, then change the table definition so that it allows only integers (i.e. smallint, bigint, int, etc). All non-integer values will be changed to 0 I believe.

Comment: Yup changing fields as soon as I fix this.. realized teh error AFTER teh data dump was done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RegExp works, but what I would do is check to see if abs() is equal to zero AND the field is not zero. I think this will be faster than RegExp.

```
SELECT id, area, city FROM `homes` WHERE (abs(area) = 0 AND area != '0') OR (abs(city) = 0 AND city != '0')
```

Comment: But what will abs() do to decimals?

Comment: We have no decimals on the system, so it's not an issue whatsoever.

Comment: `abs(area) = 0` Brilliant and simple! Thanks