# MySQL: Update a column if value is numeric only

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-update, numeric

Is there a way to update a column in mysql if value is number only?

ie. `UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA =NewValue WHERE ColumnA isnumeric`

`Column A` is `varchar(25)` and `Column A` value may be text or 1 or 2 or 23...

thank u

Comment: Well at least you could use regex in where to see if the field contains only numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql

Comment: This smells like bad database design.

Comment: it's not bad database design. i creat a job for Automatic Data Processing from excel file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use regular expression to see if your column contains number or anything else

```
WHERE ColumnA REGEXP '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Regex is invalid, it will also match rows where ColumnA has other characters beside numbers.

Comment: What I meant was to use regexp depending upon the need. That was just an example

Answer (score 5):

Use [**REGEXP()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) function

Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA = NewValue WHERE ColumnA REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA = NewValue WHERE ColumnA REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'
```

Comment: @Glavić Check my updated answer. I had added `^` & `$` in RegEx

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `INT` column and make call:

```
update myTable set IntColumn = ColumnA
```

than replace intcolumn type to varchar and update your table where ColumnA = IntColumn (Not real numeric strings will be empty or different from real numeric).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA =NewValue WHERE concat('',ColumnA * 1) = ColumnA
```

Or

```
UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA =NewValue WHERE ColumnA REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

Look at this topic [Detect if value is number in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It works for me

```
if ('value_to_check' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') {
THEN 
// Do ur work,..
}
```