# SQL order varchar as decimals

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, sql-order-by

I have a row that has both numbers ant strings. I whant to order it so that numbers will be ordered as numbers and all the strings would go to the end of table.

```
ORDER BY (
          CASE 
               WHEN `{$table}`.`{$row}` LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                    THEN CAST(`{$table}`.`{$row}` AS DECIMAL) 
               ELSE `{$table}`.`{$row}` 
          END
         ) ASC"
```

But instead the numbers are still sorted like strings.

```
Results: 
0
410
680
72
Some other string
Some string


It should be:
0
72
410
680
Some other string
Some string
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  Your `like` expression (for the intention that you have) is supported by SQL Server but not MySQL.

Comment: I had a suspision it has something to do with like

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there a way to check if string is a number with mysql?

Comment: Yes, although you don't need that in this case because of the silent conversion (unless you want something like `'1abc'` to go with the strings.  Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-value-is-an-integer-in-mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
order by (case when left(`{$table}`.`{$row}`, 1) between '0' and '9' then 0 else 1 end),
         `{$table}`.`{$row}` + 0,
         `{$table}`.`{$row}`
```

The first expression puts numbers first (or at least strings that start with a number).  The second is a nice MySQL feature that simply converts a string to a number.  The third sorts the non-numeric strings.

EDIT:

To have only numbers (instead of leading numbers) go first:

```
order by (case when left(`{$table}`.`{$row}`, 1) REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' then 0 else 1 end),
         `{$table}`.`{$row}` + 0,
         `{$table}`.`{$row}`
```

Comment: And what if i whanted the whole thing opposite? [string 10 9 4 0]

Comment: @Benedictus . . . You would add a `desc` to the first condition.

Comment: in this query 12abc will be counted as integer, right?  I'd rather count it as a string, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b9034/12/0)):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT field1
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE field1 REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
  ORDER BY CAST(field1 AS DECIMAL)
  )AS m
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT field1
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE field1 NOT REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
  ORDER BY field1
) AS mm
```

Comment: . . `union all` is not guaranteed to retain ordering.  `union` definitely will not.