# SQL - ORDER a mix of numbers and words

Tags: php, sql

I have an SQL database with I'm calling through a php file. The column can contain both numbers and words. For example it could countain:

```
1
4
clowns
12
46
```

Naturally, ORDER BY returns:

```
1
12
4
46
clowns
```

but I would like it to sort how it would sort integers with the numbers:

```
1
4
12
46
clowns
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql

Comment: Depends on the dbms used. Some dbms products have collations with numeric sorting.

Answer (score 3):

add some new columns to solve this, first order by whether or not it is a number, then by the number value, and finally alphabetically by the word value.

In MSSQL you have access to the isnumeric function.
In ORACLE you could create a custom function using [THIS](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php)
In MYSQL you could create a custom function using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75880/4347337)

```
select your_column from(
select *, 
isnumeric(your_column) as ISNUMBER,
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(your_column) = 1 THEN CAST(your_column AS INT) ELSE null END as NUMBERVALUE,
case when isnumeric(your_column) = 1 then null else your_column end as TEXTVALUE )
order by isnumber desc, numbervalue asc, textvalue asc
...
```

Comment: Please specify which dbms this works for. (ISNUMERIC is a product specific function.)